# How to get records between 5-6 months ago

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I am trying to get accounts that have a start date 5 - 6 months ago. However when trying between and Interval functions I get an error message.

> ERROR: operator does not exist: date = interval Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types

```
Select * 
from Account 
where start date between INTERVAL '5 month' and INTERVAL '6 month'
```

Comment: `Select * from Account where start date between (current_date_date - INTERVAL '6 month') and (current_date - INTERVAL '5 month')`

Comment: Main source of your error is `start date`, that should be enclosed in quotes `"start date"`, otherwise it will think you're using the `date` function improperly. For the rest, Adrian's solution is the one that will work for you.